# Hide a column in webgrid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I hide a column in a webgrid? I should be able to access those values from the grid but the user should not be able to see the column in the grid. There is no condition, but completely I want to hide those columns

My column is

```
grid.Column(header: "Phone")
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172420/mvc-3-webgrid-how-do-you-hide-columns-you-do-not-want-to-be-visible

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to just use some CSS/jQuery where 'TABLECLASS' is the name of your table's class:

```
table.TABLECLASS th:first-child, table td:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```

I do not think there is a way to do this via the built in WebGrid.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the 2nd column, for instance:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#yourGridId th:nth-child(2)").hide();
  $("#yourGridId td:nth-child(2)").hide();
  }
```