# Show/Hide Column header in webgrid dynamically

Tags: razor, webgrid

I'm displaying Dynamically selected table Columns using WebGrid i want to hide the column which is not selected.how can i hide the Column header dynamically?

I'm using Following webgrid.

```
    <div>   
    @{    
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model.oTravelReadyEntities);
    grid.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.NextPrevious);
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "WebGrid",
    headerStyle: "Header",
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(


    grid.Column("Var_AssoId", "Var_AssoId", canSort: true, format: @<text>            
    @if(item.Var_AssoId == 0){@Html.Hidden("Var_AssoId", "Var_AssoId");        
    }                                                                                               
    else{ @item.Var_AssoId}</text>),

    grid.Column("Var_AssociateName", "Var_AssociateName", format: @<text>
    @if (item.Var_AssociateName == null)
    {@Html.Hidden("Var_AssociateName", "Var_AssociateName")}
    else
    {@item.Var_AssociateName}</text>),


    grid.Column("Var_Grade", "Var_Grade", format: @<text>
    @if (item.Var_Grade == null)
    {@Html.Hidden("Var_Grade", "Var_Grade")}
    else
    {@item.Var_Grade}</text>),

    grid.Column("Char_VirtualPool", "Char_VirtualPool", format: @<text>
    @if (item.Char_VirtualPool == null)
    {@Html.Hidden("Char_VirtualPool", "Char_VirtualPool")}
    else
    {@item.Char_VirtualPool}</text>),

    grid.Column("Var_VirtualPoolCatagory", "Var_VirtualPoolCatagory", format: @<text>
    @if (item.Var_VirtualPoolCatagory == null)
    {@Html.Hidden("Var_VirtualPoolCatagory", "Var_VirtualPoolCatagory")}
    else
    {@item.Var_VirtualPoolCatagory}</text>),

    grid.Column("Char_VisaUtilization", "Char_VisaUtilization", format: @<text>
    @if (item.Char_VisaUtilization == null)
    {@Html.Hidden("Char_VisaUtilization", "Char_VisaUtilization")}
    else{@item.Char_VisaUtilization}</text>),

    grid.Column("Var_Deparment", "Var_Deparment", format: @<text>
    @if (item.Var_Deparment == null){@Html.Hidden("Var_Deparment", "Var_Deparment")}
    else{@item.Var_Deparment}</text>),

    grid.Column("Var_Vertical", "Var_Vertical", format: @<text>
     @if (item.Var_Vertical == null){@Html.Hidden("Var_Vertical", "Var_Vertical")}
    else{@item.Var_Vertical}</text>),

    grid.Column("Var_AccountName", "Var_AccountName", format: 
    @<text>@if (item.Var_AccountName == null){
    @Html.Hidden  ("Var_AccountName", "Var_AccountName")}
    else{@item.Var_AccountName}</text>),

    </div>
```

I want to hide the Column header on certain Condition.How to use conditional statement to hide Column header?

Comment: What you tried for that?

Comment: i gave if condition in format.i want to hide Corresponding Column header.How to give a conditional statement to hide the grid column including its header?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to conditionally show/hide webgrid columns that I found helpful: [MVC 3 Webgrid - how do you hide columns you do not want to be visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172420/mvc-3-webgrid-how-do-you-hide-columns-you-do-not-want-to-be-visible)