# Default Sort is not working while using WebGrid Helper With Column as hidden

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, webgrid

I am using `@grid.GetHtml` gridview to show the grid in my ASP.NET MVC4 application.

Default Sort is not working while using WebGrid Helper With Column (Primary Key) as hidden.

Using SP to fetch the web grid data and also default sort is given in SP.

My code:

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new
      {
          id = "XXXX"
      },
    tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped",
    headerStyle: "info",
    footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-row",
    selectedRowStyle: "webgrid-selected-row",
    rowStyle: "gridrow",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("AAAA", "AAAA",style:"hidecol") //Primary Column Name is “AAAA” 
    )
)
```

JQuery Code to hide Column Header of Primary Column.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("# XXXX th:nth-child(1)").hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "deafult sort is not working"? What are your expected and actual results? Also what is SP? SharePoint?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have a web grid and its sorted ASC for Column "AAAA" but I dont want to show column "AAAA" as this is my promar column and dont want to show in my page but it require for my functionalities. If i remove hide its working as expected means Sort ASC is applying for column "AAAA" but if i hide column "AAAA" Sort ASC is not applying. Hope you got my scenario. Appreciate for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Sup you can just sort the data in your controller before passing it to the view

Answer (score 1):

You could just sort the items in your controller before passing them to the view. That way they should retain the order you want:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var items = new List<obj>(){new obj(5), new obj(1), new obj(355)};
    var sortedItems = items.OrderBy(o => o.Id);
    return View(sortedItems);
}
```

And if you need a way from sorting them in the view itself, you can do something like

```
public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
{
    var items = new List<obj>(){new obj(5), new obj(1), new obj(355)};

    if (sortOrder == "ASC")
    {
        items = items.OrderBy(o => o.Id).ToList();
    }
    return View(items);
}
```

Where you call that controller from a button or whatever you need in your view